# How to filter out data of a particular country using Python Panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, multiple-columns

I do have a df containing three columns (Date, Manufacturer, Country, Sales Unit) which seems something like below:

```
Date              Country          Manufacturer       Sales Unit
22-03-2019         China               BMW                200
27-04-2013         Korea             Mahindra             150
02-02-2015         India               Tata               200
13-02-2014         China               Ford               450          
21-04-2019         India             Mahindra             432
27-05-2019         China              Toyota              212
```

I want to filter out the data of the China only, so the dataset will look something like that after filtering:

```
Date              Country          Manufacturer       Sales Unit
22-03-2019         China               BMW                200
13-02-2014         China               Ford               450
27-05-2019         China              Toyota              212
```

How to do it using Python's library Panda?

Comment: `df[df['Country'].eq('China')]`

Answer (score 1):

Two common approaches to retrieving a subset of a dataframe are the `loc` and `query` methods.

Loc example:

```py
df.loc[df["Country"] == "China", :]
```

Query example:

```py
df.query("Country == 'China'")
```

You are encouraged to look into [the pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to get a better grasp of these & related methods.